# Am I using polynomial regression right in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to do polynomial regression by pytorch. First I just tried only linear regression (b + wx).

```
model_1 = RegressionModel()
W = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad=True)
b = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad = True)
optimizer_1 = torch.optim.SGD([W, b], lr = 0.001)

x_train = torch.FloatTensor(dataset.x_data['LSTAT'])
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(dataset.data['target'])

nb_epochs = 10000

for epoch in range(nb_epochs + 1):
    hypothesis = x_train * W + b
    cost = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(hypothesis, y_train.float())

    optimizer_1.zero_grad()
    cost.backward()
    optimizer_1.step()

    print('Epoch {:4d}/{} W: {:.3f}, b: {:.3f}, Cost: {:.6f}'.format(epoch, 
    nb_epochs, W.item(), b.item(), cost.item()))
```

Then I changed and added some variables to do polynomial regression (b + w1x + w2x^2)

```
model_2 = RegressionModel()
W1 = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad=True) 
W2 = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad=True) 
b = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad = True)
optimizer_2 = torch.optim.SGD([W2, W1, b], lr = 0.0000099)

x_train = torch.FloatTensor(dataset.x_data['LSTAT'])
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(dataset.data['target'])

nb_epochs = 10000

for epoch in range(nb_epochs + 1):
    hypothesis = b + x_train * W1 + x_train * x_train * W2
    cost = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(hypothesis, y_train.float())

    optimizer_2.zero_grad()
    cost.backward()
    optimizer_2.step()

    print('Epoch {:4d}/{} W1: {:.3f}, W2: {:.3f}, b: {:.3f}, Cost: 
    {:.6f}'.format(epoch, nb_epochs, W1.item(), W2.item(), b.item(), 
    cost.item()))
```

Can I try polynomial regression like this? If not, I would be really appreciate if you let me know. I'm really noob to pytorch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. When working with larger data, it will be more efficient if you do the regression in a single matrix operation. For that, you need to first pre-compute polynomials of your input features:

```py
x_train_polynomial = torch.stack([x_train, x_train ** 2], dim=1)
```

To save some lines, you can rewrite the projection a linear layer:

```
import torch.nn as nn
projection = nn.Linear(2, 1, bias=True)
```

In the training loop, you can call:

```py
hypothesis = projection(x_train_polynomial)
```